# Using lazy load jquery plugin (by mika tuupola) with magento, fadein effect animation flickers

Tags: jquery, magento, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I'm using Mika Tuupola's jquery plugin with Magento CE 1.7.x.  I'm using a fadein animation effect on product images, by setting the class to lazy for the images, and then calling $jq191( img.lazy ).lazyload();.  Also, I'm using jquery's no conflict mode with var $jq191= jQuery.noConflict().  I don't know where the problem lies, or what code to paste in this question.  I'm hoping someone has come across this problem and can maybe shed some light with their experience.  The images are inside an anchor nested in a li tag nested in a ul tag. I'm also using twitter bootstrap. I've tried the plugin with just bootstrap, and it works fine.  But when I add magento to the mix, it causes flickering in google chrome and firefox.  It works fine in internet explorer, but even in internet explorer, it shows this white flash that moves from right to left, but the fade in itself is smooth.

**SOLUTION!**
ok, after looking at what scripts were loaded in magento that could be causing the issue. it looks like the script.aculo.us effects.js was conflicting with the jquery lazy load plugin.  i dont understand why that is, because the lazy load plugin is self contained with its own scope so it doesnt pollute the global namespace. i removed effects.js, and the flickering stopped. i have to look through lazyload, as to why its doing that. if anyone would like to explain, id appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for having pointed out that the problem was due to `effects.js`, saved me quite some time when trying to figure out what was at the origin of the flickering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to a conflict between `lazyload` internally using an `appear` event, and the `Effect.Appear` from `scriptaculous`.

It can be solved by replacing all occurences of `"appear"` by another free value (eg, `"lazyappear"`) in the `lazyload` script.

Comment: Reported this issue on the `lazyload` github repository (https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/issues/139)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above fixed some of the flixer but not completely.
This issue is related to this one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580634

Comment: Trying to use the above mentioned lazy-load method. Went over to [GitHub](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) but there is no mention whether it works for Magento v2. Furhtermore it mentions that "_you should have width and height attributes in your image tag_". Would that work on mobile phones? Having said all, if it does not work in some way(Magento v2, mobiles, etc), do you have any other free suggestions? They would be greatly appreciated.